# Rendering stylesheets from ASHX handler

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms, ashx

I'm creating a CMS, and I want to dynamically load the style from the database. I've created a ASHX handler that returns the stylesheet. I then reference the handler like this:

```
<link href="/Assets/Get.ashx?aid=1" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

When I click on the link in a browser it loads the stylesheet as expected. However, when I inspect element I find that none of the styles are being applied.

Is this something that just isn't possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your ASHX handler setting the correct Content-Type (`text/css`) on the response?